# Rewrite PHPUnit test after the at() matcher deprecation

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I used to have a PHPUnit code like that (probably not a good one as I am not able to rewrite it):

```
$authorizator->expects($this->at(0))
    ->method('isAllowed')
    ->willReturn($hasSuperPrivilege);

if (!$hasSuperPrivilege) {
    $authorizator->expects($this->at(1))
        ->method('isAllowed')
        ->willReturn($hasStandardPrivilege);
}
```

How to achieve the same behavior after the deprecation of at() method?

I don't know how many times the method will be called, so probably the willReturnOnConsecutiveCalls way is not the right one?

If the first call returns false, then the isAllowed() method must be called twice, if it returned true, then only once.

Related issue: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/4297

Tested method:

```
public function canUserdoSomething(Foo $resource, Identity $identity): bool
{
    if (
        $this->authorizator->isAllowed(
            $identity,
            $resource,
            'superPrivilege'
        )
    ) {
        return true;
    }

    if (
        $this->authorizator->isAllowed(
            $identity,
            $resource,
            'standardPrivilege'
        )
    ) {
        return $resource->hasSomeProperty();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Please share the method you are testing. This will make it easier to reason about an alternative solution.

Comment: @PhilipWeinke Attached.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with a handwritten fake so you don't have to worry about the number of calls. I did it inline in my example for brevity but if you're using the authorizator in multiple test, it makes sense to extract it into a separate class.

```
/**
 * @covers \MyClass
 */
class MyClassTest extends TestCase
{
    private $subject;

    private $authorizator;

    /**
     * @testWith ["superPrivilege", false, true]
     *           ["standardPrivilege", true, true]
     *           ["standardPrivilege", false, false]
     *           ["invalidPrivilege", true, false]
     */
    public function testCanUserdoSomething($privelege, $resourceProperty, $expected)
    {
        $identity = new Identity();
        $resource = new Foo($resourceProperty);
        $this->authorizator->addPrivilege($identity, $resource, $privelege);

        $result = $this->subject->canUserdoSomething($resource, $identity);

        self::assertEquals($expected, $result);
    }

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->authorizator = new class implements Authorizator {
            private $privileges = [];

            public function addPrivilege(Identity $identity, Foo $resource, string $privilege): void
            {
                $this->privileges[] = spl_object_id($identity) . spl_object_id($resource) . $privilege;
            }

            public function isAllowed(Identity $identity, Foo $resource, string $privilege): bool
            {
                return in_array(spl_object_id($identity) . spl_object_id($resource) . $privilege, $this->privileges);
            }
        };

        $this->subject = new MyClass($this->authorizator);
    }
}
```